# SPSS: how to create .sav file from database

Tags: mongodb, spss

We are currently building a database (MongoDB), where we offer an export of the data in .csv and .xlsx formats.

We received requests to offer also a .sav download of the data, since data manipulation (variable and value labels, missing) takes quite a lot of time. In principle, it is not very difficult to produce this when you import the Excel file into SPSS and write a script. But our database would look better, if we could directly generate a .sav file and offer this format additionally.

Does anyone know of a tool which allows this?

Thanks in advance!